# How can we use SP client side people picker in provider hosted app in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, client-side, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I have used client side people picker in sharepoint hosted app model, but in provider hosted app it does not work, because it consume some people picker related .js files from _layouts folder or internally consume some SP services.
so i just wanted to know that is there any way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot consume any SP controls (other than the chrome control) on provider-hosted apps because of dependencies to SharePoint.